# Is takeWhile a proper way to emulate break in a loop

Tags: java, java-stream

Suppose, that I need to apply some function to every element of a stream until certain condition is met. However, to check the condition I need to apply the function, so separating on `takeWhile` and `forEachOrdered` is not going to work. For example,

```
stream.map(...).takeWhile(p -> {
    try {
        write(p);
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log(e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
});
```

Here, I don't want to `log` failure many times, so once `write` fails, I would like to stop iterating.

I have doubts that this is proper (?) solution, because the result of `takeWhile` is unused and just redundant.

Is there a better way to handle the situation? Is my solution actually fine?

Comment: @nullpointer, yes, it would. That's why I can't separate `takeWhile` and `forEach`. `write` just does some thing that might throw `IOException`.

Comment: Actually, this would keep writing unless there is an exception with the `write` method or the stream exhausts otherwise. But still, it depends on `write` and `map` to say completely if `forEach` or even stream is required for this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misusing `takeWhile`. For your case, it would be enough to use `forEachOrdered`, because, if an exception is thrown, the remaining elements of the stream won't be processed:

```
try {
    stream.map(...).forEachOrdered(p -> {
        try {
            write(p);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
        }
    });
} catch (UncheckedIOException e) {
    log(e.getCause().getMessage());
}
```

Here, `e.getCause()` is the original `IOException` thrown by `write`.

Comment: Thank you, but what if `write` also might throw `UncheckedIOException`? Wouldn't I mishandle it then?

Comment: You were right, the code in the question would keep writing unless there is an exception. That shall be good to handle as a `forEach` terminal operation.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner, I see that this code catches any exception and logs it. However, I want to log only one specific type of exception thrown by `write`. I guess, in this case I have to rely on `instanceof`? (e.g. `if (e.getCause() instanceof MyException) {...} else { throw e}`)

Comment: If I am right, I would like you to include that in the answer, so that I could mark it as correct

Comment: Seriously, I think your original solution was much better. If `write` declares to throw `IOException`, it shouldn't also throw `UncheckedIOException`, but even if it does, unwrapping it at a place where you are able to deal with the contained `IOException` is the right thing to do. The `UncheckedIOException` type is not meant to introduce a new semantic.

Comment: @grepcake I've rollbacked to the original version. Holger is right: if the method `write` throws `IOException`, it shouldn't also throw `UncheckedIOException`.